# Arithmetic operations in ember handlebars

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to calculate difference between two variables in handlebars - ember js. How can I accomplish this? Is using a script tag a good idea? Following is my handlebars file

```
{{#each data in view.block.infodata.weatherData}}
    <tr>
        <td> <div><font size="3" >{{data.name}} </font></div> </td>     
        <td> <font size="3"> {{data.currentValue.tempInFarenhiet}} </font> </td>        
        <td> <font size="3"> {{data.pastValue.tempInFarenhiet}} </font> </td>
        <td> <font size="3"> {{data.currentValue.tempInFarenhiet - data.pastValue.tempInFarenhiet}}  </font> </td>              
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

Is there a function to parsefloat in handlebars?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a handlebars helper to do the calculation. Which you could use like this:

```
{{temp-difference data.currentValue.tempInFarenhiet data.pastValue.tempInFarenhiet}}
```

Create a file in the helpers folder caller `temp-difference.js`

```
export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(function( currentValue, pastValue ) {

  return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString( parseInt( currentValue - pastValue, 10) );

});
```

Comment: like seriously... 17 words in javascript to do what takes 1 machine instruction ..